# What is the fastest way to get SVG element given a position (x,y)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, d3.js

I would use

```
var element = document.elementFromPoint(x, y);
```

to get the SVG element from the original SVG. But when running my code, a network is placed over the original SVG. So it returns the network vertex, not the back svg element.

Even if I have the modified and the original SVG, what is the fastest way to find over what svg element is each vertex from the network?

So I have circles (vertex) and also background shapes. I need to get the background element that is behind a circle (vertex). I also have all (x,y) positions from each vertex.

I saw this solution using jquery:

```
$("svg").find("[x='10'][y='10']");
```

which returns all the elements that are over this position. But it looks computationally expensive, as I need to compute it in each interaction of a force-layout (d3.js) for over 1000 vertices. 
The force is always active and the user needs to interact with vertices using mouse.

This is an example:

[image: example]

I'd like to know over which square each node is, and i only know the node position.

Comment: Should the code return all of the squares the node is over, or just the top one?

Comment: Also, do you intend to have lots of squares, or just a few?

Comment: A few squares. Only the top square. The function document.elementFromPoint(x, y) does not work because the node is in the top when the function is called. Overlapping of vertices are also possible and the edges are also considered by this function. Now I also tried '$("svg").find("[x='10'][y='10']");', but it seems to get elements that have 10,10 as a position in svg file. I don't know. But when calling this function what I got was an empty list. Thank you for your attention

Comment: The basic solution I already have is compute the differences and x and y values. I did for just 2 squares. It was a first test with D3, networks and force algorithm. Now I need to expand it for more squares and vertices. The current code is just checking things like this: if x > K1, then it can not be at square K. If k2 < x < K1, it is in square K... but I have the variable Y too and it gets complicated.

Comment: If that method is working, why not keep using it?  I don't see why adding more squares and/or testing against Y makes it that much more complicated.  Just loop from the front square to the back square until (x>=xMin && x<xMax && y>=yMin && y<yMax) is true.  Am I missing something?

Comment: I think this would already work better than my drafts. I will keep searching for something faster. I'm starting the project and I see this method, the way I will find the svg elements, have great importance to the next steps. Yours idea is already faster than my. Thank you @BigBadaboom

Comment: I will spend a little time searching for some best solution, the fastest one. Another possibility is also consider Circles, only Circles or even Circles and Squares. When using circles I think I will need to calculate 'tranlate_to_zero(), theta=atan2(x,y), x=r.sin(theta) and y=r*cos(theta)' for each vertex. And also check using those polar calculations to find the circle each vertex is over. So I'm trying to guess what will be possible to be done and what will not. And checking where the point is (what element is bellow) will be calculated more than a million times in a visualization process.

Comment: So for each interaction of Force, for each vertex of a network size 1000 or 5000 (I dont have ideia what a Firefox and a common computer can run) it will: 1. compute x,y by forces; 2. check positions and wha square/cicle is bellow this vertex; recalculate position given this information.. and so on.
So it seems it will cost a lot for each vertex do this verification for each square, in each interaction. Thanks a lot, guys, for helping me

Answer (score 2):

Make the elements you want elementFromPoint to ignore (i.e. the network) pointer-events="none"

Comment: I tried and it works. But in my case I need the user-interaction with vertices. Thank you

Comment: You could always set pointer-events="none" just before you call elementFromPoint and unset it afterwards.

Comment: Each node calls the function. When one node call it, another node may be overlapping. The same for edges, and there will be a lot of edges. I think that if I remove everything and recalculate everything, it will be noticeable to the user that is interacting with the network while force is running. Am I wrong?

Comment: Is there a way to call elementFromPoint for a separate svg file or simulate a webpage (without open it), or any workaround? Because the original svg is clean, with no network in it.

Answer (score 1):

What you probably want is a nearest-neighbor algorithm. Mike Bostock has a good example [here.](http://bl.ocks.org/llb4ll/8709363)

Nearest neighbor runs in O(log(n)), and will allow for any rounding errors that result in problems with the point location.

If your nodes aren't moving around, you could also consider adding the back SVG element to the data for the nodes in the network (assuming that you've defined the network with d3), after which you can directly reference the SVG element from the data, instead of looking for it. jquery also has a `.data` method if you aren't building the network with d3.

Comment: I'm sorry I could not understand how I can use KNN to solve the problem. I added more information to the question and a picture.